# How do I convert multi public key into a single line?

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing, public-key

I'm trying to make a txt file with a generated key into 1 line. example:

```
<----- key start ----->
lkdjasdjskdjaskdjasdkj
skdhfjlkdfjlkdsfjsdlfk
kldshfjlsdhjfksdhfksdj
jdhsfkjsdhfksdjfhskdfh
jhdfkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhf
<----- key stop ----->
```

I want it to look like:

```
lkdjasdjskdjaskdjasdkjskdhfjlkdfjlkdsfjsdlfkkldshfjlsdhjfksdhfksdjjdhsfkjsdhfksdjfhskdfhjhdfkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhf
```

Notice I also want the lines `<----- key start ----->` and `<----- key stop ----->` removed. How can I do this? Would this be done with `sed`?

Answer (score 43):

```
tr -d '\n' < key.txt
```

Found on http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/rmnl-remove-new-line-characters-tr-awk-perl-sed-c-cpp-bash-python-xargs-ghc-ghci-haskell-sam-ssam-p65/

Comment: im also trying to remove the lines <----- key start -----> and <----- key stop -----> which is why i thought sed would work better..

Comment: don't have access to console right now. I have found this however http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/delete-first-and-last-lines-of-a-file-586069/ Sorry didn't see that last line.

Answer (score 19):

To convert multi line output to a single space separated line, use

```
tr '\n' ' ' < key.txt
```

I know this does not answer the detailed question. But it is one possible answer to the title. I needed this answer and my google search found this question.

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -n +2 key.txt | head -n -1 | tr -d '\n'
```

Tail to remove the first line, head to remove the last line and tr to remove newlines.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for everything you asked for in one sed, I have this...

`sed -n '1h;2,$H;${g;s/\n//g;s/<----- key \(start\|stop\) ----->//g;p}' key.txt`

But it's not exactly easily readable :) If you don't mind piping a couple of commands, you could use the piped grep, tr, sed, etc. suggestions in the rest of the answers you got.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to use `cat file.txt | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: im also trying to remove the lines <----- key start -----> and <----- key stop -----> which is why i thought sed would work better.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '^[^<]' test.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/key start/{:a;N;/key stop/!ba;s/^[^\n]*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;s/\n//g}' file
```

Gather up lines between `key start` and `key stop`. Then remove the first and last lines and delete any newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Every other answer mentioned here converts the key to a single line, but the result that we get is not a valid key and hence I was running into problems.
If you also have the same issue, please try

```
awk -v ORS='\\n' '1'  key.txt/file-name
```

Credit: https://gist.github.com/bafxyz/de4c94c0912f59969bd27b47069eeac0

Comment: While your credit is correct, the original credit goes to https://www.kevinsimper.dk/posts/how-to-convert-privatekey-into-singleline

Comment: maybe, i don't know what `bafxyz` referred tho. I referred him :)

Answer (score 1):

In vim, it's just :%s/^M//

I use this all the time to generate comma separated lists from lines.  For sed or awk, check out the many solutions at this link:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/35107-remove-line-break.html

Example:

paste -s -d',' tmpfile | sed 's/,/, /g'

Answer (score 1):

```
grep  -v -e "key start" -e "key stop" /PATH_TO/key | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/ key (start|stop) / {next} {printf("%s", $0)} END {print ""}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `man 1 ed` to join lines as well:

```
str='
aaaaa
<----- key start ----->
lkdjasdjskdjaskdjasdkj
skdhfjlkdfjlkdsfjsdlfk
kldshfjlsdhjfksdhfksdj
jdhsfkjsdhfksdjfhskdfh
jhdfkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhf
<----- key stop ----->
bbbbb
'


# for in-place file editing use "ed -s file" and replace ",p" with "w"
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s <(echo "$str")
   H
   /<----- key start ----->/+1,/<----- key stop ----->/-1j
   /<----- key start ----->/d
   /<----- key stop ----->/d
   ,p
   q
EOF


# print the joined lines to stdout only
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s <(echo "$str")
   H
   /<----- key start ----->/+1,/<----- key stop ----->/-1jp
   q
EOF
```